# Immutable local values in c# - a specific use case

Tags: c#, constants, immutability

I know that this general topic has been discussed here before. What I am interested in is if there is a good solution for my specific case:

I have a command line tool like this (simplified):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: MyTool <InputFolder> <OutputFolder>");
        return;
    }

    string inputFolder = args[0];
    string outputFolder = args[1];

    // ...
}
```

I assign names to the argument values to make the code more readable. I would also like to express that these values will not be modified later.

Neither `const` nor `readonly` can be used here because the values is not known at compile time and because they are local 'variables' and not class members.

So how could I make this code more expressive and readable?

Comment: I don't think there is a keyword for that. How about making a `struct` or a `class` where you pass your variables to `constructor` and expose them with `public get`ters? One could argue that this will make your program even more readable. :)

Comment: not an answer as it is doesnt currently exist, but could in the future https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/CSharp-Readonly-Locals

Answer (score 3):

My proposition is creating a class holding your variables

```
public class Immutable
{
    public Immutable(string[] args)
    {
         InputFolder = args[0];
         OutputFolder = args[1];
    }
    public readonly string InputFolder;
    public readonly string OutputFolder;
}
```

then

```
var m = new Immutable(args)
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it. But I would accept and array inside the constructor so that the method signature doesn't need to get changed every time a variable is added.

Comment: You do not have _both_ `readonly` _and_ `get;`. Either it is a field, or it is a property, never a hybrid.

Comment: Sure you could do that, but then in `Main()` you could still change the instance of `Immutable` to reference a different instance later in the method, so I'm not sure how much this really helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about the C# 7.2 [`ref readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-readonly-locals)?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: MyTool <InputFolder> <OutputFolder>");
        return;
    }

    ref readonly var inputFolder = ref args[0];
    ref readonly var outputFolder = ref args[1];
}
```

Comment: This comes closest to what I was looking for. Still a bit cryptic for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some sort of Inputs class where you could parse the array into its parts and make the properties that expose the parsed values readonly. Simple Example:

```
public class Inputs {
    private string[] _args;

    public string InputFolder { get { return _args[0]; } }
    public string OutputFolder { get { return _args[1]; } }

    public Inputs(string[] args) { _args = args.Clone(); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
public class ImmutableObject
{
    public ImmutableObject(string inputFolder, string outputFolder)
    {
        InputFolder = inputFolder;
        OutputFolder = outputFolder;
    }

    public string InputFolder {get;}
    public string OutputFolder {get;}
 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: MyTool <InputFolder> <OutputFolder>");
        return;
    }

    var folders = new ImmutableObject(args[0], args[1]);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Bah @antoine-v beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about local variables.
`string` is already immuttable type. Values of `inputFolder` and `outputFolder` will never changes. Of course you can assign new values to it, but you are inside one method, how big this method should be that you forget to not assign new values to it.

If values are going to be passed to other methods, they will be passed as copies, so what happen inside a method will not affect actual values of `inputFolder` and `outputFolder`.

If you still insist to have those values immutable, than consider using of types designed to be immutable.

Value tuples

```
(Input string, Output string) folders = (args[0], args[1]);

// Usage
folders.Input
folders.Output
```

Or immutable dictionary (requires  System.Collections.Immutable NuGet package)

```
var folders = 
    new ImmutableDictionary<string, string>().Add("input", args[0])
                                             .Add("output", args[1]);

// Usage
folders["input"]
folders["output"]
```

Comment: Yes, the value itself is immutable. What I was hoping for is a way to express that `inputFolder` is just another name for `args[0]` and not a variable that might get another value assigned later. I agree that this is not a big issue if the scope of the variable is small and that you should keep the scope small for other reasons as well.